# Sequence of simple functions defining Lebesgue integral chosen monotonic

Tags: lebesgue-integral, uniform-convergence

I often find it stated in Kolmogorov-Fomin's (for ex. [here](http://librarum.org/book/10022/187) in the proof of ex. 2) that the sequence $\{f_n\}$ of summable simple functions uniformly converging to $f$, that are used to [define the Lebesgue integral](http://librarum.org/book/10022/152) $\int_A fd\mu=\lim_n \int_A f_nd\mu=\lim_n \sum_k y_{n,k}\mu(A_{n,k})$ where $A_{n,k}=\{x\in A:f_n(x)=y_{n,k}\}$, can be chosen to be non-decreasing.

How can we verify that $\{f_n\}$ can be chosen so that it uniformly converges to $f$ while $\forall x\in A$ $f_1(x)\leq f_2(x)\leq...$ and while, for all $n$, $\sum_k |y_{n,k}|\mu(A_{n,k})<+\infty$? $+\infty$ thanks for any answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For constructing the integral of $f$ for $f≥0$, you don't worry if its $∞$. One explicitly writes down a formula for one choice of $f_n$, for example

$$ f_n := \sum_{k=1}^{2^{n^2}} \frac{k-1}{2^n} \mathbf{1}_{\left\{ \frac{k-1}{2^n} ≤ f < \frac{k}{2^n} \right\}} $$

Note for every $x$, only 1 summand is ever non-zero and that summand is not more than $f$. You can also convince yourself that $f_n(x)$ increases in $n$, and also by construction $f(x) - f_n(x) ≤ \frac{1}{n}$ which is a bound independent of $x$, so we have uniform convergence. Whats left to do is to show that the integral is independent of choice of approximating functions.

At this point we allow $∫f ∈ \mathbb{R}\sqcup\{∞\}$ because everything is non-negative, so tending to infinity is the only 'kind of divergence' possible. For $f$ that can take positive values as well as negative values, we only try to assign a value to $∫f$ if $∫|f|<∞ $, so the bound $∑|a_{nk}| \mu(A_{nk}) < ∞$ holds by assumption.

Comment: Forgive me: I understand why we can chose a non-decreasing sequence of summable simple functions such that $f_n\to |f|$ and $\int f_n\to\int |f|$, but I cannot grasp why the analogous non-decreasing sequence can be chosen for $f$. I know that $f=f^+-f^-$ where $\frac{|f|+f}{2}-\frac{|f|-f}{2}$ and the desired result holds for $f^+$ and $f^-$, but if $\{f^+_n\}$ and $\{f^-_n\}$ are sequences of summable simple functions uniformly converging to $f^+$ and respectively $f^-$ then $\{f_n^+-f_n^-\}$ is not non-decreasing in general. Thank you so much again!

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: I don't think its possible actually. Luckily you don't need to. I believe your book is assuming without loss $f$ and $F$ are non-negative. We need this to get 

$$f_i(x) ≤ f_j(x) \implies (f_i F)(x) ≤ (f_j F)(x)$$

as (if I understand correctly) $F$ in the general case can also be negative. By decomposing into the positive and negative parts we can recover the full result as claimed.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Kolmogorov-Fomin's can be so confusing at times. Reflecting more about it, I'm not sure I understand why our choice of $f_n(x)$ is non decreasing as $n$ increases... I've mistakingly convinced myself that, if $f(x)=|x|$ then $\forall x\in[1/2,2/3)\quad 1/3=f_3(x)<f_2(x)=1/2$: I'm surely missing something... $\aleph_1$ thanks for your patience!

Comment: Oh wow I just realised that this choice is wrong. There is a good reason books normally use $2^n$ in place of $n$ in my formula for $f_n$. Using the formula 

$$ f_n := \sum_{k=1}^{2^{n^2}} \frac{k-1}{2^n} \mathbf{1}_{\left\{ \frac{k-1}{2^n} ≤ f < \frac{k}{2^n} \right\}} $$

We avoid the problem of 'overlapping intervals' making our function decrease in some places. I will edit the answer to have the right function, thank you very much :) :) And sorry for the confusion.